# 2023 Squared From Squares

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Without moving or removing any number, replace each of the triangles by either $+$, $-$, $\div$ or $\times$, and insert as many sets of parentheses as you want, in order to make the following equality true:
$$1^2\:\Delta\:2^2\:\Delta\:3^2\:\Delta\:\ldots\:\Delta\:87^2=2023^2$$

Comment: Parenthesis are also allowed so I guess much more than that.

Comment: true, I totally miss that part :D

Answer (score 20):

As 2023 is

> 17x17x7

one easy way is to use

> $1^2\div 2^2\times 7^2\times 17^2 \times 34^2$

and somehow get rid of all other terms. The fact that $(n+3)^2-(n+2)^2-(n+1)^2+n^2$ is constant can be used to zero out any eight or more consecutive squares. Only the first gap (3,4,5,6) is shorter but there we can use $3^2+4^2-5^2=0$

One possibility:

> $(1^2\div 2^2+(3^2+4^2-5^2)\times 6^2)\times (7^2+(8^2-9^2-10^2+11^2-12^2+13^2+14^2-15^2)\times 16^2)\times (17^2+(18^2-19^2-20^2+21^2-22^2+23^2+24^2-25^2)\times (26^2+27^2+28^2+29^2+30^2+31^2+32^2+33^2))\times (34^2+(35^2-36^2-37^2+38^2-39^2+40^2+41^2-42^2)\times (43^2+44^2+45^2+46^2+47^2+48^2+49^2+50^2+51^2+52^2+53^2+54^2+55^2+56^2+57^2+58^2+59^2+60^2+61^2+62^2+63^2+64^2+65^2+66^2+67^2+68^2+69^2+70^2+71^2+72^2+73^2+74^2+75^2+76^2+77^2+78^2+79^2+80^2+81^2+82^2+83^2+84^2+85^2+86^2+87^2))$